# Should I use classification or regression model for performance discrete values?

Tags: classification, regression, correlation

I am analyzing the performance of an operating machine. The control parameters include many as fuel flow, temperature, vibration, humidity, etc. The evaluation performance results just have 2 values: success or failed. I would like to determine whether there is relationship (or correlation) between the control parameters and the performance result. Should I use classification or regression for this problem? and What model should I use?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classification problem since you want to learn to classify a set of parameters as success or fail.

Regarding correlation, you can load the data into a Pandas dataframe and run df.corr(). This will show you how correlated your variables are.

Regarding a model, you could use scikit-learn's Nearest Neighbor classifier or Support Vector Machine. There are off the shelf implementations with scikit-learn's library.

Regression would be used if you wanted to predict the future values for these parameters.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to **classify** (failed, success) you can use classification methods
In this case, you will train using a part of the data and then predict using unseen (test) data.

Some Methods:

[LinearDiscriminantAnalysis (LDA)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html)

[LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html)

[SVC in general](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

If you want to explore the **correlation** between the variables you can use other methods like:

[Pearson correlation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html)

[Spearman correlation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html)

If you use pandas module [link here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.19.2/#downloads) you can load the data with name df lets say and then use:

```
df.corr()
```

To get the correlation between the variables.

P.S: If you upload your data I could provide examples.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I do not know how to upload my data here. I am not familiar with py; I am more using R.

Comment: @Levan8421 i though you were using python. Still, you can do everything in R just search for regression etc e.g. [link](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html)